# Unable to install boot-repair

Tags: boot, boot-failure, boot-repair

I am trying to install Windows 7 on Ubuntu. I created NTFS partition for Windows 7 but I deleted a 5GB  partition so I got a error message when I reboot Ubuntu.

```
grub rescue error
```

To solve this error, I tried installing **boot-repair** software. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Boot to LiveCD
2. Connect to Internet
3. Open terminal
4. Give command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`
5. Then give  command `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

Now I get this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package boot-repair
```

Comment: Not sure why the commands you followed didn't work, I used the same commands and was able to install.  If you "deleted" rather than resized a partition you may have deleted your Ubuntu partition, in which case Boot Repair will fail to fix your problem.  If you resized your Ubuntu partition then you may be OK.   If you are going to install Windows _after_ Ubuntu, you need reformat a partition to NTFS and it should be the FIRST partition.  See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/a/158319/65969) for instructions on how to do it.

Comment: I would like to suggest Create boot repair disk, it works in  great boot repair.

Answer (score 5):

If your are using an older version of the ubuntu live cd, you might need to change the package source. (I had this problem with the Natty (11.04) live cd.)

1. Start Synaptic, and in the menu go to Settings -> Repositories. Go to the "Other Software" tab, and select the line **http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/u**... **main** and then click on the Edit button down below.
2. In the new window that pops up change the **distribution:** field to "quantal" (without quotes).
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2, except this time select **http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/u**... **(Source Code)** , and then close the window.
4. Now, either click the reload button in synaptic, **or** enter into the terminal

   > sudo apt-get update
   >
   > sudo apt-get install boot-repair

That's it! Boot Repair is now installed.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I was using a Linux Mint 12 Live CD I had around to repair my boot sector after installing Windows in another partition. Linux Mint 12 is based on Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric), and replacing that with quantal as you described allowed me to install `boot-repair` :)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar grub error after installing Lucid (10.04.4) on an older Dell and found a solution that allowed me to install boot-repair by modifying the instructions from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/245571/285018. Modifications are noted in **bold**

1. Start Synaptic, and in the menu go to Settings -> Repositories. Go
   to    the "Other Software" tab, and select the line
   http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/u... main and then click on the Edit button down below.
2. In the new window that pops up change the distribution: field to "**precise**" (without quotes).
3. **Step 3 in the referenced instructions said to change the "Type" to "Source" instead of "Binary" in the same window where you changed the field to "precise," but that was not necessary for me. I left the "Type" as "Binary"**
4. Now, either click the reload button in synaptic **and install boot-repair from there**, or enter into the terminal:

   ```
    sudo apt-get update

    sudo apt-get install boot-repair
   ```

As a side note, after performing steps 1-4 above and selecting "origin" at the bottom-left of the main synaptic page, the ppa yannubuntu was included in the list of available sources.

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure that your internet connection is ok.
- follow these steps carefully: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Getting_Boot-Repair

Answer (score 3):

wilmc's answer didn't work for me, but it was on the right track which helped me find the answer. This is what I did to get this to work.

First, type in these commands:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo nano yannubuntu*
```

You should see a line that says:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu vivid main
```

Change the word before "main" (in this case "vivid") to "precise". Save it and exit. Now simply run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it using these commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

These are the instructions from the following webpage

["Boot-Repair": Fix Ubuntu Boot Issues (After Installing Another OS Or Faulty GRUB Upgrade)](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/boot-repair-fix-ubuntu-boot-issues.html)

Comment: I think, this is the same things he has already done.

Comment: @AnwarShah it is more or less, I broke it up into separate steps.  I can only assume that he may have typed the commands wrong when he entered them into the terminal, as I was able to use the commands(typed in correctly) and was able to install without any problems.  Unless he didn't include some 404 or connection error, there is not much of a reason to think that it was any more than a syntax problem.  I just broke up the commands to give him an easy way to cut and paste in the terminal to avoid syntax errors and eliminate that as a possible problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution **based on 12.04**:

Go the **Update Manager**

Open **Settings**

Go to the **2nd tab** (**Other Software**)

Find the line saying `http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair`

Select it

Press Edit

Add  `/ubuntu` at the end of the line

..  The line should now look like this:

..  `http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu`

Press **Ok**, **Close**, e.t.c. (whatever is needed to save and close)

**Go back to the terminal and repeat the usual installation process**

It will install normally now

In the Terminal commands do NOT change anything 
(Do NOT add `/ubuntu` at any terminal command, I didn't try it)

At least this is the solution that worked for me.

Good luck!

..............................

*In the Terminal I used*

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`